# Why cannot $2^x=m^n+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

$x,n,m >1$ and $x,n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$

I've tried to solve it myself, but I'm getting nowhere, so apologies if it's an irritatingly basic question.

Whilst I'm on it, is it true that $y^x \ne m^n+1$ ($y>1, y \in \mathbb{Z}$)? There's probably a glaringly obvious counterexample I'm overlooking.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Diophantine equation is $$2^x = 1 + m^n.$$

- Since the left hand side is even $m$ must be odd, let $m = 2r+1$.
- Since $m^n + 1$ factors into $(m+1)(\cdots)$ when $n$ is odd, $n$ must be even, let $n = 2u$.

Putting these two facts together and applying the binomial theorem gives $$m^n = (2r+1)^{2u} = (4r(r+1)+1)^u = \sum_{k=0}^u \binom{u}{k} [4r(r+1)]^k$$

Plugging this into our original equation, and pulling out the first term of the sum we have
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
2^x
&=& 1 + \binom{u}{0} [4r(r+1)]^0 + 4 \sum_{k=1}^u \binom{u}{k} 4^{k-1}[r(r+1)]^k \\
&=& 2 + 4 M \\
\end{array}$$ for some $M$, this is impossible unless $M=0$, then $x=1$ and $u=0$ and $m$ can be anything.

Comment: Pretty proof. 

[spacefiller]

Comment: +1 from me , although it could be longer and clearer.

Comment: Actually, could you elucidate as to *why* it can't factor like that?

Comment: @Alyosha, it forces $m$ to be $2^r-1$ which makes the other factor $m^{n-1} - m^{n-2} + \ldots + 1$ odd (it's just $1 + 1 + 1 + \ldots + 1 = 1$ when viewed mod 2) which can only happen if it's $1$ (in that case we have the solution $2^1 = 1 + 1^1$).

Comment: Is that argument equivalent to saying: $m^n+1=(m+1)(m^{n-1}-m^{n-2}+m^{n-3}-m^{n-4}....-m^1+m^0)$ only if $n-1$ is odd (so both the $m^{n-1}$ part and the $m^0$ part do not have a $-1$ coefficient?

Comment: @Alyosha, we are considering n odd, so n-1 is even.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant, I wasn't counting the 0.